# double free or corruption with shared pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

So the essence of my problem is this:

```
//Big.h
class Big{
    public:
        int a, b;
};

//Mini.h
class Big;
class Mini{
    public:
        Mini(float a, shared_ptr<Big> ptb):ma(a), me(-a), ptb(ptb){};
        float ma, me;
        shared_ptr<Big> ptb;
};

//main
int main(){
    std::list<Mini> lm;
    if(true){ //Or some sub function or rutin
        Big big; big.a = 100; big.b = 200;
        Mini derp(5, shared_ptr<Big>(&big));
        lm.push_front(derp);
    }
  //Do something
};
```

Compiles fine but it gives a "*double free or corruption*" when exiting main (in the full program this is just a sub function)

I suspect the [`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) to `big` is being freed at some point and then again when exiting main, but I'm not sure and have no idea of how to fix it. Can someone please explain to me the reason of this error?

I red that I had to `NULL` the pointer to but I don't know where.
Or maybe I'm just using the wrong smart pointer or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're constructing a `shared_ptr` with a pointer to an existing object on the stack. Don't do that; that's not how `shared_ptr` is meant to be used. Ordinary stack objects should never be deleted or freed. The object it's pointing at is supposed to be on the heap, i.e. created using `new` or the equivalent.

The recommended way to create a `shared_ptr` is through `make_shared`:

```
auto p = make_shared<Big>();
```

or the old-fashioned way:

```
shared_ptr<Big> p(new Big);
```

Comment: just one thing i don't get. the **auto** keyword. I thought that was only to ask the compiler decide the type. Is it necessary or could I just make the type **Big**?

Comment: The actual type is shared_ptr<Big>. I used auto there just to save the bother of writing that out, since the type is clear from the expression. I generally think it's reasonable to use auto when the type is obvious from the expression on the right, and writing it out in full would not give the reader any new information.

Answer (score 4):

Objects managed by a `shared_ptr` must be constructed in dynamic scope, i.e. allocated with `new`.

```
Big big;
big.a = 100;
big.b = 200;

Mini derp(5, shared_ptr<Big>(&big));
```

And here, you're shoving a pointer to an object that was constructed in automatic scope into a `shared_ptr`. `shared_ptr` now thinks it owns this object, and it gets to decide when it is going to `delete` it.

But when this object in automatic scope goes out of scope and gets destroyed, this will make this `shared_ptr` very, very sad.

Use `new` to construct this object, instead of constructing it in automatic scope.

Comment: I'd suggest using `make_shared` by default, unless there is a reason not to (using `weak_ptr`/custom deleters)

Answer (score 1):

The `shared_ptr` points to a stack object. You cannot free stack objects. Here's how to use `shared_ptr`:

```
auto big = std::make_shared<Big>();
big->a = 100;
big->b = 200;
Mini derp(5, big);
```

Answer (score 1):

To correct your program, you need to allocate your `Big` object on the heap.

```
if(true){ //Or some sub function or rutin
        auto big_shared_ptr = std::make_shared<Big>();
        big->a = 100; big->b = 200;
        Mini derp(5, big_shared_ptr);
        lm.push_front(derp);
    }
```

This way, the variable won't be destroyed when your if(true) block returns as well as when the shared_ptr is cleaned up - which would cause a double free.